# Problema con el control Chart de visual studio en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy intentando hacer que se muestren los valores que se introducen en un datagridview en un gráfico del control Chart.

Tengo dos problemas:

1. Lo que quiero es generar por cada fila que tengo en el datagrridview una serie nueva que se debe de pintar en la gráfica, pero pinta todos los datos en la misma linea en vez de en las coordenadas que se pasan.

*Ejemplo:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que utilizo:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{   
    nom_serie = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    chart1.Series.Add(nom_serie);//Creamos la nueva serie
    chart1.Series[nom_serie].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bubble;
    chart1.Series[nom_serie].XValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
    chart1.Series[nom_serie].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
    chart1.Series[nom_serie].Points.Add(Convert.ToDouble (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()), Convert.ToDouble (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()));

}
```

2. El segundo problema que tengo es que quiero poder poner nombre a los ejes para que se vea en la gráfica pero no he conseguido que aparezcan escritos. He utilizado este código:

> ```
>   chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Name=nomEjeY;
>   chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title=nomEjeX;
> ```

3. Y por último me gustaría poder saber si habría alguna manera de que los ejes pudiesen aparecer en el centro formando una cruz como la imagen que muestro a continuación:

*Ejemplo:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. Para el primer punto, creo que debes crear nuevas series. Puedes orientarte mirando este [enlace](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-Line-Chart-Graph-in-Windows-Forms-Application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) para el punto 3.

Comment: Buenas! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. ¿A que te refieres con crear nuevas series?
con
 chart1.Series.Add(nom_serie);//Creamos la nueva serie
No estoy creando la nueva serie?

Comment: En cuanto al chart lo que yo quiero hacer es que los ejes aparezcan marcados como en la imagen, pero luego los datos se van a visualizar con bubbles, no pretendo hacer una grafica lineal, que igual en la descripción que hice no esta muy claro